# Reinstall Win10 but forget deactivate it first

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10-upgrade, deactivation

I have product key for Win 7 Pro.
I've upgraded to Win 10 Pro.
All went great, but after some time I've decided to switch back for Win 7 Pro.
So, I've downloaded the image, deleted whole partition, instaled fresh Win 7 Pro and now the system doesn't want to recognize my product key.
I guess it's because I've forgot to deactivate it in Windows 10 when I was deleting it.

IS there any way how to get of this situation ? 
I do not really want to buy another Windows. 
I am fine with using just Windows 7 Pro.

Thank you

Comment: If it is an OEM product key, we could contact with OEM or activate it with sticker messages. If it is a retail product key, but you can't find the product key any more, we could contact with Microsoft support for activate through online chat or phone.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently your online activation limit for Windows 7 was reached
and was so marked by the Microsoft license server.

It might be possible to deactivate Windows 10 by reinstalling it from scratch, since it will then
be automatically activated by digital entitlement, and then can be
deactivated by entering in an elevated Command Prompt the command :

```
slmgr /upk
```

However, I don't know if this will decrease the online activation limit
for the Windows 7 key with which you originally upgraded to Windows 10.

Failing that, I suggest to phone Microsoft Support, explain your problem and
supply a proof of purchase for the Windows 7 Pro product key.
You should be using Windows 7 with SP1 for getting support.

Support might give you a new key for activating Windows,
or alternatively can always bump up or reset the online activation limit
of your existing key. Windows 7 is currently on extended support,
so Support will answer.

But I strongly advice staying with Windows 10, unless this presents
unsolvable problems.
Windows 7 is not very secure when compared with Windows 10.